# Create New React Native app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I am getting an error on creating my first react native app.
I am using following guide - 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app

```
$ npm install -g create-react-native-app
--Worked fine
$ create-react-native-app my-first-native-app
--app created without errors
$ npm start
--gives error

Error: React native is not installed. Please run `npm install` in your project directory.
1:09:05: Error starting packager: Error: Couldn't start project. Please fix the errors and restart the project.
    at C:\xdl\src\Project.js:1329:11
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\reactJs-projects\my-first-native-app\node_modules\xdl\build\Project.js:1735:191)
    at C:\reactJs-projects\my-first-native-app\node_modules\xdl\build\Project.js:1735:361
    at <anonymous>
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-first-native-app@0.1.0 start: `react-native-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-first-native-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Tried fixing with downgrading npm to version 4 as recommended all over that version 5 has bugs.

```
npm i -g npm@4
```

I have also tried latest npm but neither of them worked.

When I run `npm install` on my project directory, instead of installing/updating my packages, it is giving following error

```
npm ERR! cb() never called!
npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

I see all dependencies downloaded in **node_modules** though

Any suggestion on what I have missed?

What I also noticed is when the app is created (using create-react-native-app my-first-native-app) it also added following error  in console

```
yarn install v0.21.3
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning jest-expo > jest > jest-cli > istanbul-api > istanbul-lib-hook@1.2.1: 1.2.0 should have been a major version bump
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react-native-web-maps/-/react-native-web-maps-
0.1.0.tgz: invalid tar file".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\reactJs-projects
\\MyNewNativeApp\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Failed to install
```

Thank You!

Comment: I tried @GosulsEz solution, but it didn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying different versions, I ended up using yarn and it worked on first instance. If anyone struggles with similar problem, then I would recommend using Yarn and move on. One can switch back to npm after the app is created. This is very common issue reported and for many developers it works with certain version.

Answer (score 2):

after create your project with

```
$ create-react-native-app my-first-native-app
```

after you should enter your project folder :

```
$ cd my-first-native-app
```

and then open emulator or connect to tour device and run with

```
$ npm start
```

or

```
$ react-native run-android
```

pay attention you had installed android-SDK and android-JDK and your emulator is running

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall your NPM/YARN and get the newest version of React Native i have this problem too

Comment: Run npm install or yarn install after that npm eject

Comment: I created a new app after node and npm update so it should bring all new packages, can you please explain npm eject and how it would solve the problem?

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, but this is ios and android folder with packages

Answer (score 0):

Create new project using command : **npx react-native init ProjectName**

Create new project using particular version of react native :
**npx react-native init ProjectName --version X.XX.X**

After that go to project location
**cd ProjectName**

Run application on android platform
**npx react-native run-android**